# Error using Iconv Translit to remove accented characters

Tags: linux, shell, iconv

I want to create a function to remove accents from a text recorded in a variable, I tried to use Iconv but instead of removing the accent the accent is moved to the side of the letter.

used code

```
texto=$(echo $text | iconv -f UTF-8 -t us-ASCII//TRANSLIT//ignore)
```

input text

```
ÁÁÁÁÉÉÇÇãõê
```

Output Text

```
'A'A'A'A'E'ECC~a~o^e
```

Required result

```
AAAAEECCaoe
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce it on linux; only in bsd